# Combining two normal random variables

Tags: math, statistics, normal-distribution

suppose I have the following 2 random variables :

X where mean = 6 and stdev = 3.5
Y where mean = -42 and stdev = 5

I would like to create a new random variable Z based on the first two and knowing that : X happens 90% of the time and Y happens 10% of the time.

It is easy to calculate the mean for Z : 0.9 * 6 + 0.1 * -42 = 1.2

But is it possible to generate random values for Z in a single function?
Of course, I could do something along those lines :

```
if (randIntBetween(1,10) > 1)
    GenerateRandomNormalValue(6, 3.5);
else
    GenerateRandomNormalValue(-42, 5);
```

But I would really like to have a single function that would act as a probability density function for such a random variable (Z) that is not necessary normal.

sorry for the crappy pseudo-code

Thanks for your help!

**Edit** : here would be one concrete interrogation :

Let's say we add the result of 5 consecutives values from Z. What would be the probability of ending with a number higher than 10?

Comment: What is the problem of wrapping the code you provided as a function? It generates two random numbers and preform your task well. What are you looking for?

Comment: Well, I will have many variables such as the one represented by Z here (combinations of normal variables). I am looking for the best way to represent them because I will have to combine such variables together eventually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I would really like to have a
>   single function that would act as a
>   probability density function for such
>   a random variable (Z) that is not
>   necessary normal.

Okay, if you want the density, here it is:

```
rho = 0.9 * density_of_x + 0.1 * density_of_y
```

But you cannot sample from this density if you don't 1) compute its CDF (cumbersome, but not infeasible) 2) invert it (you will need a numerical solver for this). Or you can do [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) (or variants, eg. importance sampling). This is costly, and cumbersome to get right.

So you should go for the "if" statement (ie. call the generator 3 times), except if you have a very strong reason not to (using quasi-random sequences for instance).

Comment: thanks, see the comment I made on the question, I will eventually have to combine variables that are a combination of normal variables...would that change your answer?

Comment: By the way, the technical term for this is a "mixture distribution."  Your distribution is a mixture of two normals.

Comment: As belisarius pointed out, this would be a mix of a Binomial Distribution with two Normal ones...Conclusion from answers : simulation is the way to go with if statements... Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

If a random variable is denoted x=(mean,stdev) then the following algebra applies

```
number * x = ( number*mean, number*stdev )

x1 + x2 = ( mean1+mean2, sqrt(stdev1^2+stdev2^2) )
```

so for the case of X = (mx,sx), Y= (my,sy) the linear combination is

```
Z = w1*X + w2*Y = (w1*mx,w1*sx) + (w2*my,w2*sy) = 
    ( w1*mx+w2*my, sqrt( (w1*sx)^2+(w2*sy)^2 ) ) =
    ( 1.2, 3.19 )
```

link: [Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) look for Miscellaneous section, item 1.

PS. Sorry for the wierd notation. The new standard deviation is calculated by something similar to the pythagorian theorem. It is the square root of the sum of squares.

Comment: thanks I will have a look into that but I am not sure in my case the standard deviation of Z is meaningful to me, because the raw result can be very far from the mean (either tight around 6 or -42) a.k.a. I do not want Z to be a normally distributed variable representing the two others...because if I am not mistaken, the combination of X and Y is definitely not normally distributed?

Comment: The OP is not adding Normal distributions, he is just choosing one or the other based in a 90%-10% weight

Answer (score 2):

This is the form of the distribution:

```
ListPlot[BinCounts[Table[If[RandomReal[] < .9,
    RandomReal[NormalDistribution[6, 3.5]], 
    RandomReal[NormalDistribution[-42, 5]]], {1000000}], {-60, 20, .1}], 
    PlotRange -> Full, DataRange -> {-60, 20}]
```

[image]

It is NOT Normal, as you are not adding Normal variables, but just choosing one or the other with certain probability.

**Edit**

This is the curve for adding five vars with this distribution:

[image]

The upper and lower peaks represent taking one of the distributions alone, and the middle peak accounts for the mixing.

Comment: Thanks for the nice visual touch! This would be the PDF for a single value taken from Z yes :) What would be the best way to get the PDF for lets say 5 consecutive values from Z? a.k.a : Let's say we add the result of 5 consecutives values from Z. What would be the probability of ending with a number higher than 10?

Comment: @ibiza This answer is just "visually" showing the distribution, because you already got at least one correct answer for calculating it (see @Alexandre's answer). Nevertheless I will elaborate a graph for adding 5 vars :).

Comment: thank you for your time, this is very helpful. So basically, there is no easy way to compute this function (the second chart) and I should stick with if statements in my code..?

Comment: Technically, shouldn't the x-axis of the second chart should go down to -210 since it is (highly improbable, 0.10^5) possible to get -42 for 5 consecutive times..! :p Also, could you provide the code to generate this chart please? Thanks again!

Comment: @ibiza You are mixing a Binomial Distribution with two Normal ones, and then adding up those. The easy way is to go for simulating, but surely you can compute the resulting distribution with some work

Comment: @ibiza I just trimmed the plot :)

Comment: I will accept Alexandre's answer, as you pointed to it in your first comment here...I hope you take no offense, you were as much helpful :) Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @ibiza Of course. My answer here was just a complement. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward and generically applicable solution is to simulate the problem:

Run the piecewise function you have 1,000,000 (just a high number) of times, generate a histogram of the results (by splitting them into bins, and divide the count for each bin by your N (1,000,000 in my example). This will leave you with an *approximation* for the PDF of Z at every given bin.

Comment: Why bother? This is a well defined problem with a simple solution (assuming normal distribution).

Comment: @jalexiou, this sounded straight out of a decision theory textbook;  while the 0.9/0.1 bernoulli trial is simple enough here, it might at some point be replaced by a more complex condition - where the known solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of unknowns here, but essentially you just wish to add the two (or more) probability functions to one another.

For any given probability function you could calculate a random number with that density by calculating the area under the probability curve (the integral) and then generating a random number between 0 and that area.  Then move along the curve until the area is equal to your random number and use that as your value.

This process can then be generalized to any function (or sum of two or more functions).

**Elaboration**:
If you have a distribution function f(x) which ranges from 0 to 1.  You could calculate a random number based on the distribution by calculating the integral of f(x) from 0 to 1, giving you the area under the curve, lets call it A.

Now, you generate a random number between 0 and A, let's call that number, r.  Now you need to find a value t, such that the integral of f(x) from 0 to t is equal to r.  t is your random number.

This process can be used for any probability density function f(x).  Including the sum of two (or more) probability density functions.

I'm not sure what your functions look like, so not sure if you are able to calculate analytic solutions for all this, but worse case scenario, you could use numeric techniques to approximate the effect.

Comment: This looks like a promising answer but I have difficulties grasping the essential of it...would you mind elaborating a bit for my comprehension please?

Comment: Perhaps start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function.  I am looking at this problem fresh and just giving a mathematical basis for a solution.  I have never tried to implement such code, where as others here seem to have more direct experience with the problem. (i.e., Alexandre)