# Generating random values from non-normal and correlated distributions

Tags: math, statistics, distribution, probability

I have a random variable X that is a mixture of a binomial and two normals (see what the [probability density function would look like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454513/combining-two-normal-random-variables/4454941#4454941) (first chart))
and I have another random variable Y of similar shape but with different values for each normally distributed side.

X and Y are also correlated, here's an example of data that could be plausible :

```
    X     Y
1.  0    -20
2. -5     2
3. -30    6
4.  7    -2
5.  7     2
```

As you can see, that was simply to represent that my random variables are either a small positive (often) or a large negative (rare) and have a certain covariance.

My problem is : I would like to be able to sample correlated and random values from these two distributions.

I could use Cholesky decomposition for generating correlated *normally distributed* random variables, but the random variables we are talking here are not normal but rather a mixture of a binomial and two normals.

Many thanks!

Comment: you need the mathematical relationship between the variables (X Y) to be able to sample them in a joint distribution

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for your comment. As of now, I am not sure how to calculate the mathematical relationship between the variables (X Y)...maybe it's just the formulation that I don't understand? Also from my first question that you participated in (where you visually computed the PDF), one user was saying that calculating the joint distribution could be quite painful and cumbersome...so I did not research how to do that and don't know yet how it should be done

Comment: If you are able to use Cholesky, then you know the relationship. It is just the value(s) in the lower left of the matrix. (The L part of the LU.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, you don't have a mixture of a binomial and two normals, but rather a mixture of two normals. Even though for some reason in your previous post you did not want to use a two-step generation process (first genreate a Bernoulli variable telling which component to sample from, and then sampling from that component), that is typically what you would want to do with a mixture distribution. This process naturally generalizes to a mixture of two bivariate normal distributions: first pick a component, and then generate a pair of correlated normal values. Your description does not make it clear whether you are fitting some data with this distribution, or just trying to simulate such a distribution - the difficulty of getting the covariance matrices for the two components will depend on your situation.